# How to put other images on a photo Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I take a photo in my Android app.
I want to put other images in that photo to create effects 
like a ballon of conversation, a legend, and others.

After that I want to save this Image in another Bitmap.

I try put my photo as a background image, and put another ImageViews components under that and try to take a printScreen of my screen. But I think it isn't the best way to do what I Want.

Can anybody help me?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best bet would be create a Canvas based on your photo (you'll need it as a mutable Bitmap) and then use the `drawBitmap()` to draw another bitmap onto yours (you'll have to pass it the offset and Xfer mode).

The original mutable bitmap will now contain the combination of of your images

Comment: I use onTouchEvent to find a place to draw a image. And I draw with drawBitmap() canvas method as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

Just put the photo in the background, and then put ballon of conversation in front of photo.

If you want to combine photo and ballon effect, you could use [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

Just record the effect's coordinate.